# How to implement a universal login in Android like Facebook and Google

Tags: android

If there is some sdk (let's assume facebook here) that is implemented in multiple apps.

Now facebook asks a login one time from the user (the first time user uses fcbk app/sk on device). Once logged in, if any app (in same device) tries to access the sdk again, it does not ask user to login again (but just the permissions).

How does Facebook/Google know that user is already logged in that device once? Do they store Mac address of device. Do they have some universal sharedprefs? Do they have db/file on local sdcard.

I want to create similar functionality for my app. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is both simple and complicated, but generally it centers around registering an account with the AccountManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) which then handles authentication requests coming from other apps.

Here is a step-by-step that should still be current enough to get you started:
http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2

Comment: wblaschko, this is exactly what i was looking for. much appreciated and many thanks

Comment: This was not an easy task. If anyone needs help with this please let me know

Comment: Agreed, the fundamentals are pretty easy, actually getting it working is another story. Glad you got it figured out!